# Ionic wkWebView is not defined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have purchased an ionic 5 app from codecanyon but issue is its only working with ionic serve (Mean browser) when i build it on android its showing no data in app and in device console showing error of

`ReferenceError: wkWebView is not defined`

I already tried to add or remove plugins multiple time by

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

Also this line is also added in config.xml

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

Can any one please tell how can i solve this or any hint to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Post plugin install Kindly remove the platform and Add platform
Please execute below commands

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova platform rm ios/android
ionic cordova platform add android/ios
```